# CSS- Avatars randomly change size

Tags: html, css

Just like the title suggests, the avatar on my main page appear to change shape randomly (the second image is the correct image) [image]

[image]

HTML:

```
 <div class="jumbotron" style="padding:20px;">
               <img class="avatar-picture" style="float: left" src='/avatar-pictures/{{this.avatar}}' />
```

CSS:

```
img.avatar-picture {
  width: 230px !important;
  height: 230px !important;
}
```

As mentioned, this change appears randomly when I refresh the page. Could someone please explain what's going on?

Comment: Your code looks good, I don't feel it is anything to do with the current code, you think there are other css code which may caused this? you can take out `!important` which is not needed.

Comment: are you using something like bootstrap?

Comment: then if you want to do something responsive you should never specify px of an image. you should use width:number% and height:auto